# Retrieve only some params from a node at Firebase (web)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does firebase allows me to fetch only some params from a node ?

Example User has: `id, name, email, birthday, zip_code`

But I only want `id` and `name` for an specific search.

To get users list at web app I can do:

```
var database = firebase.database();
return firebase.database().ref('/users).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('list de users: ');
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

But this retrieves all users params, how can I get only id and name from `/users` at Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a subset of children to fetch for a single query.  When you query at a location in the database, you will always get all children of that location, as deeply nested as they go.

If you only want certain children, you will have to make a separate request for each one of them at their fully specified paths.